# HTA: Can a Link act as a Select? And How to Store HTA state in a way I can Recover it when I re-open it?

Tags: vbscript, hta

EDIT 2:
Here is exactly what I need:
[Change dropdown option with jQuery/Javascript on link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737479/change-dropdown-option-with-jquery-javascript-on-link-click)

Whatever, I could not make this to work with the HTA! Any help is much appreciated!

Hello all and thanks in advance for your answers!
I've been working in a self project, and accomplished at least 75% of what I want. Whatever, those two questions on the title are the things that are making me stuck!
Here is one image of how my program looks right now:

[Part of my "program"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYX7l.png)

Ok, as you can see, it has LOTS of drop down menus, and that's ok.
But for ease of use and for questions of aesthetics, I'd like to migrate one of those drop down to the menu on the left.

This select has 5 options, and according to what I chose, it will change something inside a .txt file.
The problem is that I simply CAN'T make this select menu work on the left menu, whatever, as a "select", it work's fine.

Here's an example of the code that's working:

```
<select size="1" name="OptionChooser43" inputbox id = "searchInput43">
<option value="Equals = 2">Adicionar Expression</option>
<option value="Equals = 3">+ 1 Expression</option>
<option value="Equals = 4">+ 2 Expressions</option>
<option value="Equals = 5">+ 3 Expressions</option>
<option value="Equals = 6">+ 4 Expressions</option>
```

So, this select works just fine, and changes a part of my .txt with "Equals = &" accordingly. 
But if I try to embed it on the left menu, I cant manage it to work.
Here's the code: One of one of the working functions, and another of the non working "select":

```
<a href="#">Upload</a>
            <ul>
      <li><a onclick="LoadPreset_1" style="cursor:pointer;">Upload Preset 1</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="LoadPreset_2" style="cursor:pointer;">Upload Preset 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        *******NON WORKING********
  <li><a id="" option value="Equals = 2" style="cursor:pointer;"></option></li>
  <li><a id="" option value="Equals = 3" style="cursor:pointer;">+ 1 Expression</option></li></a></div>
```

I've tried to: Create a new sub for each of the items of the menu, but as soon as I click it, it executes changes to the txt, without execute the changes that I've done with my drop menus.

I tried to use it as a select, but it doesn't answer my commands.

I googled it every way I could think of, no success.
And I even did not want to ask, because it maybe really simple and could make you angry! haha

---

Second:
I would like to store everything I do on the HTA, in a way that when I open it again, it would be the way I left.
Each drop menu has from 127 to 256 different options, and it would be really nice to have it stored once I open the HTA again!
I also, would like to be able to load the preset-info if I wish.
I've searched how to store data on xml, database... But again, was not successful.
I could go really far alone, but this time I hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Even after cutting off what I did not need, I still ended up with almost 700 lines, so, here is the attached hta.
[HTA File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykv22vtz4wllw7t/stack.hta?dl=0)

Comment: Better take one question at time. If your hta code is not too large, please [edit] and add that to the question.

Comment: Found an answer for one of my questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538435/change-value-of-a-select-list-using-onclick-in-href

Comment: Simple questions won't "make us angry", but the questions answered before are not preferred. Also, the second question is far too broad to answer, you should try to solve the task by yourself, and if you get stuck, then ask a specific question.

Comment: Hey Teemu! I appreciate your answer and totally agree! It was my fault, I must confess... But I swear that I've searched many times with different terms, and got no success. I was surprised when I found another topic that I hadn't read... Anyway, could you only point where I should start seeking for the answer? Maybe some link, it will be really helpful! Thank you again :)